# Word to describe a person who is on a journey to find the meaning of life

Tags: single-word-requests

> John quit his job to go off in the world to find the truth in the world and meaning of life. He was not planning to get a job or be at one place but instead use his life savings to fund his journey. When his friend asked him what he should tell others when asked what he is doing, he replied. "Tell them I'm a [...]"

What is a noun that describes someone who seeking out truth or meaning of life as their primary or sole life purpose?

Comment: This seems far too broad because countless words come to mind, none more clearly correct than the others: *Sinnsucher, pre-adult, adolescent, unsatisfied, supernaturalist, spiritualist, nutjob,
charlatan, seeker, hopeful, inquirer, windmill-tilter, unicorn-chaser,
pilgrim, wanderer, palmer, peregrin, dreamer, youth, child, mystic,
acolyte, apprentice, visionary, daydreamer, idealist, stargazer, utopian,
romancer, escapist, fantasizer, predisillusioned, deluded, irrealist,
unrealist, irrationalist, apragmatist, life-waster,* and so on — for the meaning of life is not found but created.

Answer (score 3):

*Seeker* a person or thing that seeks.

*Seek*:
1. to go in search or quest of:

*Ex.: to seek the truth*

2.to try to find or discover by searching or questioning:

*to seek the solution to a problem.*

Answer (score 2):

***Voyager*** from the Walt Whitman poem, *The Untold Want* in *Leaves of Grass*

> The untold want by life and land ne'er granted,
>
> Now, voyager, sail thou forth, to seek and find.

Source, [Bartleby.com, Great Books Online](http://www.bartleby.com/142/289.html)

From [The Humanities and Social Sciences Review](http://www.universitypublications.net/hssr/0305/html/R4ME58.xml)  (Author Larry D. Griffin)

> The second line of Walt Whitman’s short poem “The Untold Want” reads:
>   “Now, Voyager, sail thou forth, to seek and find.” Olive Higgins
>   Prouty entitles her 1941 novel Now Voyager, and Irving Rapper names
>   his 1942 film, starring Bette Davis, Now Voyager. Both the novel and
>   the film explicate the meaning of how one must change their life now
>   as presented through the character of Charlotte Vale. After the 1940’s
>   the concept enters into mainstream twenty and twenty-first century
>   American enterprises and cultural activities, including American law,
>   pop psychology, fiction and nonfiction books, poems, songs, art, and
>   the nomenclature of other material culture artifacts

If you look up **"voyage of self discovery"**, this is a representative example of what you will find:  [The Hero's Journey: A Voyage of Self Discovery](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1845902866)

> In this extraordinary workshop presented here for the first time in
>   print, Stephen Gilligan and Robert Dilts truly take you on a voyage of
>   self-discovery. The Hero's Journey examines the questions: How can you
>   live a meaningful life? What is the deepest life you are called to,
>   and how can you respond to that call? This book is about how to
>   discover your calling and how to embark on the path of learning and
>   transformation that will reconnect you with your spirit, change
>   negative beliefs and habits, heal emotional wounds......

Answer (score 1):

Consider vision quest. 
It may have a more mystical connotation than you intend. 
And it would be "Tell them I'm on a ..."
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vision_quest

Answer (score 0):

Closest I could find

*free spirit*

> a person with a highly individual or unique attitude, lifestyle, or imagination; nonconformist.

[Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/free-spirit)